# Equal spacing between title page paragraphs?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, article

This is my first time using Latex, and I was wondering if it was possible to vertically justify paragraphs. In this case, I am using the document class article, and I would like the title to be on top, the author tag to be in the middle and the date to be at the bottom, with equal spacing between each element.

I succeeded in aligning everything towards the center, but it isn't exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to show what you have tried and what is not working?

Comment: put up a screen shot of your result and a hand sketch of what you required as output

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you have done but hopefully the following will help you.

```
% titleprob.tex SE 528758 equal spacing between title page entries

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}  % centering the entries
The Title
\vfill
The Author
\vfill
The Date
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The `\vfill` macro basically pushes apart the text above and below it. In the above, used twice, it puts equal space between the **The Title**, **The Author** and **The Date** entries, filling up the page.